# Problems with checkboxes arrays [JS, Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

In my html code, I have 2 checkboxes arrays, like the following ones:

```
<?php for($i=0;> i<array.length;i++){?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="taski[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tooli[]" disabled>
<?php }?>
```

What I want to do with JS/Jquery if a checkbox in taski is selected, the checkbox with the same index in tooli becomes enabled.

Comment: Other than lack of research effort, the question itself seems fine. It's certainly not unclear or **too broad**

Comment: i find some information, but it was very confusing beacuse the accesed to DOM in a very different way

Answer (score 1):

See the comments inline in the code:

```
// Bind change event to all the elements having name as taski[]
$('[name="taski[]"]').on('change', function() {
    // If this checkbox is checked then disable the next checkbox to this
    $(this).next(':checkbox').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));


    // OR
    $(this).next(':checkbox').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/j35xk2ep/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/80L44fjx/ (Thanks To @RGraham)

Comment: You have access to the standard `checked` property too: http://jsfiddle.net/80L44fjx/